# How do I import Spring Security OAuth Authorization Server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I am trying to build out a security implementation in Java.

According to the [announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/01/spring-authorization-server-0-2-1-available-now) from earlier this month, v0.2.1 of Spring Authorization Server is available. That page even privides a reference:

`compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.2.1'`

Including this in my project (in the dependencies block) – using Netbeans 12.6, Java 17, Gradle 7.3.1 – gives an error. In the first instance,:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments
[org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.2.1]
on object of type
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

On that basis, changing it to to `implementation`, the error is then:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.2.1.
```

What is the trick to including Spring Authorization Server?

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Spring Authorization Server is compiled against JDK 1.8. We haven't tested with 17. Please try the sample first https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples and then adjust your application build.

Comment: Thanks @JoeGrandja. I've tried the sample, and it does nothing; or at least I can't get it to do anything. (From within the IDE; I've never been able to get any command-line access to do what it's supposed to.) In NetBeans, I see only an empty Sub Projects (even though looking at the files, there's a load more there) and a Custom Build Logic script which turns into a separate project, but the whole thing kicks up a stick if I try to do anything with it. (Possible gradle changes?) From that starting point, adjusting my application build doesn't compute.

Answer (score 0):

Now It was moved to production, you can find in this [Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/08/19/spring-authorization-server-goes-to-production) and the most recently [Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/01/spring-authorization-server-0-2-1-available-now)

> compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.2.0'

[Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server)

Comment: Thanks. Except that still doesn't work. Changing original post to reflect more detail (and bring up-to-date with 0.2.1).